# Update multiple rows in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My current table:

```
id | count | group_id
1    1      employee   
2    2      employee   
3    3      employee   
4    4      employee
```

What I want:

```
id | count | group_id
1    4      employee   
2    3      employee   
3    2      employee   
4    1      employee
```

What i've attempted

```
 UPDATE table SET count = 4 WHERE count = 1 AND group_id='employee';
 UPDATE table SET count = 3 WHERE count = 2 AND group_id='employee';
 UPDATE table SET count = 2 WHERE count = 3 AND group_id='employee';
 UPDATE table SET count = 1 WHERE count = 4 AND group_id='employee';
```

For obvious reason this does not work because it executes each query row by row, so my result is wrong. I think i'm looking for a way of updating multiple tables with one query?

Comment: What is the logic behind the new values?

Comment: It's actually a column named ordering. And they want to reverse that ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific case can be solved like this:

```
UPDATE table SET count = 5 - count
WHERE count between 1 and 4 AND group_id= 'employee';
```

A more general solution, use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE table SET count = case count when 4 then 1
                                    when 3 then 2
                                    when 2 then 3
                                    when 1 then 4
                         end
WHERE count between 1 and 4 AND group_id = 'employee';
```

Comment: my bad, it's supposed to be 'employee'